# How to use COALESCE in DB2 while dealing with Date Field (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, coalesce

I'm trying to query a date field Adm_DT which has null values like below :

```
select id, COALESCE(Stud.Adm_DT,'') from Student Stud
```

I'm getting an sql error

```
SQL Error [42818]: THE OPERANDS OF AN ARITHMETIC OR COMPARISON OPERATION ARE NOT COMPARABLE. SQLCODE=-401, SQLSTATE=42818, DRIVER=4.9.78
```

Comment: Empty string is not a valid date apparently. What the exact **valid date** value do you want to get, if `Adm_DT` IS NULL?

Comment: If empty string is not a valid date, I would insert Null value only, then I won't be needing coalesce.. Do I have any other option?

Comment: There is nothing about INSERT in your question. Where do you want to insert the result of your SELECT? To a string column of another table? Or what's your final goal?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase it, I needed to have a blank/empty string where I have null as my Adm_DT, but since that's not possible.. I am exploring other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COALESCE(TO_CHAR(ADM_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), '')`.